# OData V4 failing to properly serialize list of POCO(?)s containing a System.Object property

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I'm writing an OData V4 service with Web API 2 using the currently available OData NuGet packages.

I have an Entity Set of class `Foo` like so:

```
class Foo {
    string SomePropertyUnrelatedToThePost {get; set;}
    ...
    IList<Bar> TheImportantPropertyList {get; set;}
}
```

`Bar` doesn't have too much going on:

```
class Bar {
    string Name {get; set;}
    int? Group {get; set;}
    object Value {get; set;}
}
```

In use, Bar#Value is never assigned anything other than basic values, but some are primitives and some are not: bool, byte, char, short, int, long, string, Decimal, DateTime...

I am registering the Foo set as the docs instruct, using an ODataConventionModelBuilder like so:

```
...
builder.EntitySet<Foo>("Foos");
```

and registering my `Bar` as a complex type with `builder.ComplexType<Bar>();` does not seem to change the outcome here.

The problem is that when I return a Foo object in my ODataController, the JSON response does not include Bar#Value.

```
{
  ...
  "SomePropertyUnrelatedToThePost": "Foo was here",
  ...
  "TheImportantPropertyList": [
     {
        "Name": "TheAnswer",
        "Group": null
     },
     {
        "Name": "TheQuestion",
        "Group": null
     }
   ]
}
```

Adding to my confusion is the fact that I can manually serialize a Foo in my controller method like so:

```
var settings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;//.CreateJsonSerializer();
var s = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
...
var json = Encoding.Default.GetString(...);
```

to produce a properly serialized result:

```
{
  "SomePropertyUnrelatedToThePost": "Foo was here",
  ...
  "TheImportantPropertyList": [
     {
        "Name": "TheAnswer",
        "Value": 42,
        "Group": null
     },
     {
        "Name": "TheQuestion",
        "Value": "What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?",
        "Group": null
     }
   ]
}
```

Am I configuring OData incorrectly? Do I have some other core misunderstanding?
 As I wrote this question it occurred to me that if I changed my model to include the System.Type of the assigned Value property, I could write a custom serializer, but it seems like it shouldn't have to come to that.

**Edit**: When I'm manually serializing my `Foo`, I'm not using the default OData serializer, I'm using a new Newtonsoft JsonSerializer. The default OData serializer and deserializers simply do not like properties of type `Object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this going.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656229/json-net-as-a-webapi-2-odata-serializer-vs-odatamediatypeformatter) post helped.  Being new to OData, it took a while to get through the documentation, as most of it is out of date.

In my `WebApiConfig.cs`, I used the new method of injecting an `ODataSerializerProvider` into OData:

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "api/v1", b =>
               b.AddService(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => builder.GetEdmModel())
                .AddService<ODataSerializerProvider>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => new MySerializerProvider(sp)));
```

MySerializerProvider:

```
internal sealed class MySerializerProvider : DefaultODataSerializerProvider
{
    private MySerializer _mySerializer;

    public MySerializerProvider(IServiceProvider sp) : base(sp)
    {
        _mySerializer = new MySerializer(this);
    }

    public override ODataEdmTypeSerializer GetEdmTypeSerializer(IEdmTypeReference edmType)
    {
        var fullName = edmType.FullName();

        if (fullName == "Namespace.Bar")
            return _mySerializer;            
        else
            return base.GetEdmTypeSerializer(edmType);            
    }        
}
```

In my custom serializer, I noted OData will not automatically convert a `DateTime` to a `DateTimeOffset`.  MySerializer:

```
internal sealed class MySerializer : ODataResourceSerializer
{
  public MySerializer(ODataSerializerProvider sp) : base(sp) { }

  public override ODataResource CreateResource(SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, ResourceContext resourceContext)
  {
      ODataResource resource = base.CreateResource(selectExpandNode, resourceContext);

      if (resource != null && resourceContext.ResourceInstance is Bar b)
          resource = BarToResource(b);

      return resource;
  }

  private ODataResource BarToResource(Bar b)
  {
      var odr = new ODataResource
      {
          Properties = new List<ODataProperty>
          {
              new ODataProperty
              {
                  Name = "Name",
                  Value = b.Name
              },
              new ODataProperty
              {
                  Name = "Value",
                  Value = b.Value is DateTime dt ? new DateTimeOffset(dt) : b.Value
              },
              new ODataProperty
              {
                  Name = "Group",
                  Value = b.Group
              },
          }
      };

      return odr;
  }
}
```

I realize this is a pretty specific question and answer but I hope someone finds it useful.

Comment: Can you possibly explain WHY you needed this?  Also, can you post your EDM Configuration?  Thanks

Comment: Thank you, this is one of the few solutions posted online that builds for me, but when I call it, I noticed the routing has stopped working. Did you have to do anything else to that builder above for the entity set? @Victor Wilson