# How do I remove carriage returns from the JSON output of my WebAPI service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I have created a Web API service that outputs JSON which is to be consumed by a KendoUI datagrid. Here's the rub: the KendoUI datagrid is VERY picky about the JSON code it consumes; it must not have any kind of carriage returns/line feeds. It has to be one big block of unformatted JSON.

We worked with someone from Telerik and they set up some kind of proxy (https://cors.io/?http://js01.consultwithus.us/odata/vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard), but it's just a band-aid.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // enable CORS
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // we must set odata to version 2
        var vers = new Version(2, 0);

        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.DataServiceVersion = vers;
        builder.MaxDataServiceVersion = vers;
        builder.EntitySet<vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard>("vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard");
        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}
```

I want my output to look like [this](https://cors.io/?http://js01.consultwithus.us/odata/vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard), but right now it just looks like [this](http://js01.consultwithus.us/odata/vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard).

---

UPDATE 12/28/2018

Here is the code for my controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://js01.consultwithus.us", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class vw_FilesToBeProcessed_DashboardController : ODataController
{
    private CSS_DevEntities db = new CSS_DevEntities();

    // GET: odata/vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard> Getvw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard()
    {
        return db.vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard;
    }

    // GET: odata/vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard(5)
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard> Getvw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(db.vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard.Where(vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard => vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard.Files_PK == key));
    }

    // PUT: odata/vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard(5)
    public IHttpActionResult Put([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard> patch)
    {
        Validate(patch.GetEntity());

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard = db.vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard.Find(key);
        if (vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        patch.Put(vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!vw_FilesToBeProcessed_DashboardExists(key))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Updated(vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard);
    }

    // POST: odata/vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard
    public IHttpActionResult Post(vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard.Add(vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (vw_FilesToBeProcessed_DashboardExists(vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard.Files_PK))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Created(vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard);
    }

    // PATCH: odata/vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard(5)
    [AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
    public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard> patch)
    {
        Validate(patch.GetEntity());

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard = db.vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard.Find(key);
        if (vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        patch.Patch(vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!vw_FilesToBeProcessed_DashboardExists(key))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Updated(vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard);
    }

    // DELETE: odata/vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard(5)
    public IHttpActionResult Delete([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard = db.vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard.Find(key);
        if (vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard.Remove(vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool vw_FilesToBeProcessed_DashboardExists(int key)
    {
        return db.vw_FilesToBeProcessed_Dashboard.Count(e => e.Files_PK == key) > 0;
    }
}
```

I had Visual Studio scaffold this for me based on my EDM.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to remove the formatting in the JSON string. You can do so using Newtonsoft.Json

```
   var jtoken = JToken.Parse(strValue);
   var formattedValue = jtoken.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

Comment: Where would I do this? In the Controller or the WebApiConfig?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is controlled by the `JsonSerializerSettings.Formatting` setting. According to [the documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Formatting.htm), the default value is `None`, meaning no line breaks or indents.

So if you *are* seeing new lines and indenting in your output, then that setting was changed to `Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented` somewhere. One of two things happened:

1. That setting was set in that specific controller/action, or
2. The default settings have been changed. It clearly hasn't been changed in the `Register` method, but it could be changed at any point by setting `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`.

Basically, search your entire solution for any reference to `Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented`.

*Update:* You're using `ODataController`, which changes the serializer that is used. So it's not using Json.NET to serialize anymore. There is [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20802282/1202807) about how to make it use Json.NET. That example only shows *de*serialization, so you'll have to make the class for serialization too. Kind of annoying.

Comment: I have searched the entire solution for any instance of "json", 'indent", "format", etc. Nothing like what you're talking about shows up.

Comment: I just read your update. I think it has to do with OData. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your controller method that is creating your JSON.   However I can guess you have some kind object.  Since you mention C# I'll vote for Newtonsoft too but instead suggest JsonConvert.SerializeObject() as the formatter.  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Something like:

```
var myResult = GetMyResult();
var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myResult);
return response;
```

Comment: I've edited my question to include the code for my controller.