# Automatic LocalDate casting to string CassandraDriver

Tags: c#, cassandra

I have a model with a bunch of properties in Cassandra and C#, so to prevent myself having to assign manually every value from a normal Prepared Statement (or a script that does it for me), I started using the [Mapper Component](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.16/features/components/mapper/). However, CQL `date`s are automatically mapped to [`LocalDate`s](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-csharp-driver-api/api/Cassandra.LocalDate.html) which are serialized into a JSON object with Date, Month and Year properties and I need a normal string.

I gave a look into `MappingConfiguration.Global` which has the [`Define`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-csharp-driver-api/api/Cassandra.Mapping.MappingConfiguration.html#Cassandra_Mapping_MappingConfiguration_Define_Cassandra_Mapping_ITypeDefinition___) and [`ConvertTypesUsing`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-csharp-driver-api/api/Cassandra.Mapping.MappingConfiguration.html#Cassandra_Mapping_MappingConfiguration_ConvertTypesUsing_Cassandra_Mapping_TypeConversion_TypeConverter_) methods, but the first seems to not have what I'm looking for and I wasn't even able to implement the `TypeConverter` class it expects as a parameter on the latter, since it has a syntax I've never seen (and I don't even know if it does the job).

So I was wondering, are there any built in options in the CassandraDrive to achieve what I want?

If anyone wants to give a look to my custom TypeConverter, this what I thought would work:

```
using System;
using Cassandra;
using Cassandra.Mapping.TypeConversion;

namespace Api.Helpers
{
    public class LocalDateConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        protected override Func<TDatabase, TPoco> GetUserDefinedFromDbConverter<TDatabase, TPoco>()
        {
            Func<LocalDate, string> converter = date => 
                String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", date.Year, date.Month, date.Year);
            return converter;
        }

        protected override Func<TPoco, TDatabase> GetUserDefinedToDbConverter<TPoco, TDatabase>()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

With that method declaration syntax I don't know where I'm supposed to indicate what types I want the converter to apply. This code fails with `Can't convert 'System.Func<Cassandra.LocalDate, string>' into 'System.Func<TDatabase, TPoco>'`.

Another solution non related to the Cassandra driver was a custom Json Converter, but I'm also using OData, which uses a [custom serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656229/json-net-as-a-webapi-2-odata-serializer-vs-odatamediatypeformatter).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```cs
public class CustomTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    protected override Func<TDatabase, TPoco> GetUserDefinedFromDbConverter<TDatabase, TPoco>()
    {
        if (typeof(TDatabase) == typeof(LocalDate) && typeof(TPoco) == typeof(string))
        {
            Func<LocalDate, string> func = date => date?.ToString();
            return (Func<TDatabase, TPoco>) (object) func;
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected override Func<TPoco, TDatabase> GetUserDefinedToDbConverter<TPoco, TDatabase>()
    {
        if (typeof(TDatabase) == typeof(LocalDate) && typeof(TPoco) == typeof(string))
        {
            Func<string, LocalDate> func = dateStr => dateStr == null ? null : LocalDate.Parse(dateStr);
            return (Func<TPoco, TDatabase>) (object) func;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

You can provide a custom converter to the Mapper or LINQ via the `MappingConfiguration` object:

```cs
var mc = new MappingConfiguration().ConvertTypesUsing(new CustomTypeConverter());

// LINQ
var table = new Table<Poco>(session, mc);

// Mapper
var mapper = new Mapper(session, mc);
```

For this to work you have to change your property type to `string` and tell the driver that the property maps to a `LocalDate` column:

```cs
public class Poco
{
    [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.PartitionKey]
    [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.Column("project_type", Type = typeof(int))]
    public ProjectType ProjectType { get; set; }
    
    [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.Column("date", Type = typeof(LocalDate))]
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't use attribute based config, it looks like this:

```cs
var mc = new MappingConfiguration()
            .ConvertTypesUsing(new CustomTypeConverter())
            .Define(
                new Map<Poco>()
                    .PartitionKey(s => s.ProjectType)
                    .Column(s => s.ProjectType, c => c.WithName("project_type"))
                    .Column(s => s.Date, c => c.WithDbType<LocalDate>()));
```

You also need to define your mappings in this `MappingConfiguration` instance instead of `MappingConfiguration.Global` (unless you're using attribute based config).

Just make sure to always use the same `MappingConfiguration` instance instead of creating multiple ones because this is where the driver stores the generated prepared statements.

Comment: "You also need to define your mappings in this MappingConfiguration instance instead of MappingConfiguration.Global (unless you're using attribute based config)." - is there any explanation of why is that?